# can a 4028 work with 3.3v?

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, decoder

Simple question, can the bin-to-dec decoder CD4028 ([datasheet](https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/cd40/cd4028bms.pdf)) work connected direct to a raspberry pi gpio ? powered from the 3.3v line at the pi, grounded there, and 3 gpio with pull down resistors connected to the inputs of the chip. Will this lead to 3v in the decoded output?

I keep on checking the datasheet but.. it sounds like chinese to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should work at that voltage. The output may be between VDD/2 and VDD, so 1.65V and 3.3V, but typically you may see 2.8V. Most of the 5V specs show 4.5V as the VOH for example, so performance at 3.3V may be similar.